# How to calculate sum of order in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

If I have order_id of 15 with subtotal of 10$, $20 that belong to seller_id of 1, another order_id of 15 with subtotal of 15$ that belong to seller_id of 2. How can I get a total for each seller.

Right now I'm getting the sum for the whole order of 15 even though it has different seller_id. This is how the table looks like: 
[image]

This is the logic of how I calculate total right now

```
$product = product::find($productId);
           OrderProduct::create([
            'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
            'Subtotal' =>$item['pro_price'] * $item['quantity'],
            'total' => $total += $item['pro_price'] *   $item['quantity'],
```

this is the blade

```
@foreach ($order->orderItems as $item)
@if($item->product->user_id == $userID)
    <td>{{ $item->product->Subtotal }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->$totals }}</td>
@endif
@endforeach
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did not understand the orders total are subtotal. Try to explain better

Comment: subtotal is obtained by multiplying price to quantity. The total will be the sum of subtotal. So product "A" with quantity 1 and price $5 can have subtotal of $5. product "B" with quantity 2 and price $5 have subtotal of $10. so the total is $5 + $10-> $15 @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro

Comment: i can not understand this statement, sorry: "If i have order_id of 15 with subtotal of 10$, $20 that belong to seller_id of 1"

Comment: One order can have multiple products and these products belong to different sellers(users who listed the products).  when a user submit an order, every seller receive his order.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro if you don't understand, you can look at the link above to see how the table looks like.

Answer (score 2):

You can do with SQL:

```
$totals = OrderProduct::select("seller_id", DB::Raw("SUM(Subtotal) AS sub_total"))
    ->groupBy('seller_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: That throws an error `Incorrect integer value: '[]' for column 'total' at row 1` @Giacomo

Comment: it seems an insert or update error. Are you sure u are useing this code?

Comment: I have updated controller , in the question you can check @Giacomo

Comment: $totals is a laravel object, its not integer. You can not use it in the next insert.

Comment: Please check the updated controller and blade , to see what I have tried because am getting `Undefined variable: totals` @Giacomo